# The Pearson's product–moment correlation coefficient

Tags: statistics, correlation

The Pearson's product–moment correlation coefficient is
    $
r_{xy}=\dfrac{\sum_{i=i}^n(x_i-\overline{x})(y_i-\overline{y})}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=i}^n(x_i-\overline{x})^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=i}^n(y_i-\overline{y})^2}},
$ 
where

$n$ is sample size.

$x_{i},y_{i}$ are the individual sample points indexed with $i$.

$\overline{x}=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$ (the sample mean); and analogously for ${\bar {y}}$.

Let $\mathbf{u}=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1-\overline{x}\\
\vdots\\
x_n-\overline{x}\\
\end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{v}=\begin{bmatrix}
y_1-\overline{y}\\
\vdots\\
y_n-\overline{y}\\
\end{bmatrix}$, and $\theta$ be the angle between $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$.

Clearly, $r_{xy}=\dfrac{\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{v}}{\lVert \mathbf{u}\rVert\lVert \mathbf{v}\rVert}=\cos \theta$.

**My questions:**

1. Is there any geometric meaning/deeper meaning of the $\theta$? Why is $r_{xy}$ is equal to $\cos \theta$?
2. Can we see the $\theta$ in the graph of $y$ vs $x$?

Comment: Don't know if it is useful, but there is a mention of this on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#Geometric_interpretation). Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235673/is-there-any-relationship-among-cosine-similarity-pearson-correlation-and-z-sc, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123651/geometric-interpretation-of-multiple-correlation-coefficient-r-and-coefficient.

Comment: And perhaps https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/users/rabbee/correlation.pdf.